# My CSS doesn't change my HTML any idea why?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and am trying to use a class in my `style.css` that I created and want to use across a `<div>` ...

My CSS class:

```
.dave {
    font-size: 56px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:red
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="dave">
    TEST
</div>
```

But my text "TEST" doesn't change.  I've tried saving and clearing cache but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `style.css` file linked to your html file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you link user css style file in header?
Example:

```
<head>
   <title>Ajax Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its either you didn't link your `style.css` to your HTML file, or it could be due to other errors such as, placing `<style>....</style>` in your `style.css`